# How can I decode a ZZFeatureMap?

Tags: qiskit, encoding

I've encoded a basic 2x2 image into a quantum circuit using a ZZFeatureMap in Qiskit. Is there any way I can verify that this encoding was correctly done?

My first thought was to try to decode this ZZFeatureMap to get back my original image, though I can't find how to do this.

Here is the code I used:

```
image_matrix = np.array([[0.51171875, 0.12890625],
                         [0.04296875, 0.3671875 ]]) #normalized greyscale image

feature_map = ZZFeatureMap(4, reps=1)

encode = QuantumCircuit(4)
encode.compose(feature_map, range(num_features), inplace=True))
encode = encode.assign_parameters(image_matrix.flatten())
```

Thanks for your help.